# Poor LED dimming performance

Tags: led, dimmer-switch, low-voltage

I recently bought this [LED dimmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0076HPM8A) to drive these [LED bulbs](http://www.walmart.com/ip/General-Electric-78385-GE-Energy-Smart-LED-7W-R20-Floodlight/29391017) on my recessed lights.  The fixtures have a built in transformer that drops the voltage to 12v, but I'm bot sure if they are MLV or ELV transformers.

Anyway, the crux of my problem is that the dimmer only slightly dims the lights.  I started with halogen lamps and an older dimmer which was able to dim the lights nicely using the same fixtures.  But the new bulbs and dimmer kind of suck together.  Do I need a different dimmer?  Are these bulbs a poor choice or is this just the reality of LED bulbs?

Leviton published a document laying out [bulb compatibility](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=67WHp0a2jqlkkeIRa7UzNA&label=IBE&appName=IBE&minisite=10251) that may or may not shed light on this.  They also published a [document on MLV vs ELV low voltage lighting units](http://www.lutron.com/zh-TW/ResourceLibrary/362219.pdf), which I'm not sure I fully digested just yet.  Anyone else run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem (mostly) solved.  It turns out most dimmers have a way to adjust the minimum level of the dimmer.  The way to adjust my dimmer was very unintuitive, but it allowed me to crank it down to about 10%, where it shipped with a minimum brightness of about 50%

Lutron has a nice video on their [dimmer site](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/StandAloneControls/C.Ldimmers/Overview.aspx) that shows how to make the adjustment.  Other brands of dimmers have different ways of adjusting the minimum output.

[image: http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/PublishingImages/StandAloneControls/C.Ldimmers/setting_dimming_range_video.jpg]